# text-to-speech-to-wav in Delphi

Tags: delphi, wav, sapi

I imported the SAPI type library into Delphi.  I can output speech to the PC speakers with this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Voice: TSpVoice;
begin
  Voice := TSpVoice.Create(nil);
  Voice.Speak('Hello World!', 0);
end;
```

I can output speech to a `.wav` file with this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Voice: TSpVoice;
  Stream: TSpFileStream;
begin
  Voice := TSpVoice.Create(nil);
  Stream := TSpFileStream.Create(nil);
  Stream.Open('c:\temp\test.wav', SSFMCreateForWrite, False);
  Voice.AudioOutputStream := Stream.DefaultInterface;
  Voice.Speak('Hello World!', 0);
  Stream.Close;
end;
```

The problem is that when I play back the `.wav` file it sounds terrible, like it's using a really low bitrate.  Audacity tells me the file is mono 16-bit 22.05kHz but it sounds much worse than that.

How do I output speech to a mono 16-bit 44.1kHz `.wav` file that will sound exactly the same as speech output directly to the PC speakers?  I could not figure out how to modify the second code sample to set the bits per sample and the bitrate.

**Follup-up:** Glenn's answer solves the bitrate issue.  Thanks for that.  But the quality of the speech output to the `.wav` file is still inferior to what is output directly to the speakers.  I used screen recording software to record the output from the first block of code as [helloworldtospeakers.wav](http://www.jgsoft.com/support/helloworldtospeakers.wav).  The second block of code, with Glenn's line added, produces [helloworldtowav.wav](http://www.jgsoft.com/support/helloworldtowav.wav).  The second file clearly has some distortion to it.  Any ideas?

Comment: I imported it as well into XE8 but can't get it to speak at all and it's asking for 3 parameters. pwcs: PWideChar; dwFlags: Cardinal; outpulStreamNumber: Cardinal

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the [Format attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on your file stream object.  It's an [SpAudioFormat type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722554%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which has a [Type property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you use to set the audio format.  That's an [enumerated type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which has a great many options, so you'll need to study them to get what you want.

This line should get it for you (at least with the version of type library I used).

```
Stream.Format.Type_ := SAFT44kHz16BitMono;
```